# How do I use ducks correctly in Sakuna: Rice and Ruin?

Tags: sakuna-of-rice-and-ruin

At some point in the game, Kaimaru shows up with ducks to help out at the paddy. The game says they will eat my rice once it grows and to just lock them up, but at what point is that? 1/2/3 Offshoots? Sprouting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'll eat your rice once they (the ducks) grow, not when your rice reaches a certain stage. Just remember to either release them or butcher them for meat before Spring.

Comment: Everything I've looked up except for this says that the ducks will eat the rice once the -rice- starts sprouting. Are you sure that it isn't the rice that gets to the growing stage and will be eaten after a certain point??